# Changing the defintion of shell builtins (eg echo) for all subsequent invocations but only within the scope of current shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, echo

I have a shell script (say `test.sh`) which calls more shell scripts (not written by me). These other shell scripts (say `test2.sh` and `test3.sh`) are complicated which I do not want to edit (for reasons of not messing as well as keeping the option of update alive)

`test2.sh` and `test3.sh` has several calls to various shell builtins (eg `echo`). I want to change the definition of (example) `echo` in test.sh so that whenever `test2.sh` is called, I get a modified `echo` of the type

```
echo [test2] blah blah
```

Then before invoking `test3.sh` I want to alter `echo` once again so that all the `echo`'s of `test3.sh` work as-

```
echo [test3] blah blah
```

I have tried doing that with `alias`, `export`, `function` etc. none of which works as desired. I am including my examples below -

file :: `test.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

#alias echo='function __echo(){ /bin/echo [DB] $* ; unset -f __echo;}; __echo  ' # does not work
echo()  { /bin/echo [test2] $* ; }; # works only within test.sh. test2.sh does not see this function. exporting does not help.
echo "blah" "blah"; # echoes [test2] blah blah
./test2.sh "one more arg" "second arg";
echo()  { /bin/echo [test3] $* ; }; # no luck once again
./test3.sh "test3 arg1" "test3 arg2";
```

file :: `test2.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/echo "First arg = \"$1\""; # no problem here
/bin/echo "Secnd arg = \"$2\"";
echo $1 # behaves as the usual echo
echo $2
echo $*
```

Any ideas how to do it? If possible not just for `echo` but for other utilities too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had it right with `export`, but since shell functions aren't just normal variables, you need to use the special `-f` flag:

```
export -f echo
```

I think the implementation details depend on the version of Bash, but on the one I have handy, `export -f` works by creating an environment variable named `BASH_FUNC_the_function_name()` and setting it to `() { the_function_body ; }`. When Bash starts up, it searches for environment variables of that form, and creates the appropriate functions. (A quirk in this functionality is what enabled [the Shellshock security vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_%28software_bug%29).)

Comment: After all the [test] job is over, I would like to reset `echo` to it's usual behavior. How do I un`export` it?

Comment: @Magguu: `unset -f echo`. (Though `function echo() { builtin echo "$@" ; }` would also work.)

Comment: please see my new (cumbersome) solution.

Answer (score 0):

Though @ruakh's suggested modification of my original approach works well, it messes with other things. If `test2.sh` or `test3.sh` have redirected `echo`s then none of those redirected `echo`s will work properly. I want only those lines directed to `stdout` to be affected.

Since then I have found a new solution, which admittedly is somewhat cumbersome.

file :: `test.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "blah blah"; # no change here
y=`./test2.sh "arg 1" "arg 2" 2>/dev/null`
while read -r x
do
echo "[test2] $x";
done <<< "$y"; # correctly appends [test2] before every output of test2.sh

#similarly for `test3.sh`
```

now even if `test2.sh` contains line of the form

```
echo "some text" > file1;
```

only those lines actually coming out to stdout will be affected.

But now every invocation of `test2.sh` must be changed :(

Comment: Why not just define your `echo` function to check whether stdout is a terminal, and delegate to the builtin `echo` if it's not? That is: `function echo () { if [ -t 1 ] ; then ... ; else builtin echo "$@" ; fi ; }`

Comment: (Or, since the only special aspect of your `echo` is that it prints something extra at the start: `function echo () { [ -t 1 ] && builtin echo -n "[test2] " ; builtin echo "$@" ; }`)

Comment: It is a good idea and much more concise however there are some problems too- 

1. if `test2.sh` uses `printf` instead of `echo`, then I do not get the desired outcome

2. even otherwise if `test2.sh` outputs something to `stderr` via `echo "blah blah" 1>&2` that also gets appended with extra text.